# GooglePlus login handle result

Tags: javascript, polymer

On my Polymer-Page I try to login to my google-plus page and retrieve my name and cover-photo url.
For that purpose I use a `google-signin` element that runs the following function when login finishes:

```
loginSuccess: function(e){
    console.log("Success!");
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get( {'userId' : 'me'} );
        request.execute(function(retr){
            console.log("Data Loaded");
            console.log(retr);
            this.myFunction(retr);
        });
    });
}
```

Up to "Data Loaded" everything works great, also the console prints out the whole result object from google plus. But I am not able to execute functions (`this.myFunction`) or access data from polymer there. How do I store the result data from the gapi-request into my polymer variables???

Thanks, Malte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out, that i chose the wrong way to get my profile-data.

There is a polymer element to get data from the google-api called `google-api-loader` (http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-apis/components/google-apis/#google-api-loader). I use that element the following way additionally to the `google-signin` element:

`<google-api-loader id="plus" name="plus" version="v1"
        on-google-api-load="{{displayProfile}}">
</google-api-loader>`

Here the function `displayProfile`

```
    displayProfile: function(){
        if (this.signedIn && this.$.plus.api) {
            var request = this.$.plus.api.people.get({"userId": "me"});
            request.execute(function (resp) {
                this.userData = resp;
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }
```

It works awesome and I get access to the data via `this.userData`. Here it another example: https://github.com/Scarygami/google-signin-samples/blob/master/elements/google-signin-status.html

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Ajax result, the `this` context is different. You need to setup a variable before your ajax request, or before your function to access it, like so :

```
self: this,

loginSuccess: function(e){
    console.log("Success!");
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get( {'userId' : 'me'} );
        request.execute(function(retr){
            console.log("Data Loaded");
            console.log(retr);
            self.myFunction(retr);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. The console says:  `Success!
Data loaded
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` ... any idea?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Like, the whole object containing the displayProfile function.